# Why does Hibernate say that BIGINT is an invalid datatype?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm using a Hibernate `SessionFactory` and the auto-table-creation option, but when I want to start Tomcat, the database is not started and the following error messages appear in the console:

> 2015-10-14 23:07:26 DEBUG SQL:104 - create table TEACHER (ID bigint not null, firstName varchar(255), lastName varchar(255),
>   primary key (ID), unique (ID))
>
> 2015-10-14 23:07:26 ERROR SchemaExport:426 - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: create table TEACHER (ID bigint not null, firstName
>   varchar(255), lastName varchar(255), primary key (ID), unique (ID))
>
> 2015-10-14 23:07:26 ERROR SchemaExport:427 - ORA-00902: invalid datatype

This is my config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation=
      "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sante.gestion" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:spring-configured />

    <!-- DataSource -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" />
        <property name="username" value="gestion" />
        <property name="password" value="gestion" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Session Factory Declaration -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.sante.gestion.model</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Transaction Manager is defined -->
    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <!-- Enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />

</beans>
```

And this is my object model:

```
@Entity(name = "COURSE")
public class Course implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8736444902161357518L;

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
                        generator = "COURSE_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "COURSE_SEQ",
                          sequenceName = "COURSE_SEQ",
                              initialValue = 1,
                                  allocationSize = 999999999)
    @Type(type = "java.lang.Long")
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String name;
```

Comment: Your configuration has this line: `<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>` but I would think you would want an Oracle dialect, wouldn't you?

Comment: Your object model code is for the `COURSE` entity, but the error messages refer to the `TEACHER` table/entity. It looks like your root problem is occurring in a different domain object and you may be getting confused about the error messages (we have all made the same mistake). If you look at your `TEACHER` entity, you will probably find the problem. Or you could add more detail about the `TEACHER` entity to your posting, because we won't be able to help you without that additional detail.